# Storing historical data with Java and Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, design-patterns, class-design

This is a problem about historical data handling.
Suppose you have a class MyClass like the following one:

```
class MyClass {
    String field1;
    Integer field2;
    Long field3;

    getField1() {...}
    setField1(String ...) {...}

    ...
}
```

Now, **suppose I need to make MyClass able to store and retrieve old data, what's the best way to do this?**
The **requirements** are to persist the classes through Hibernate, too. **And to have at most two tables per "entity"**: only one table or one table for the "continuity" class (the one which represents the entity which evolves over the time) and another table for the historical data (as it's suggested [here](http://www.thomas.beck.name/pdmp/hoc.pdf))
Please note that I have to be able to assign an arbitrary valid time to the values of the fields.

The class should have an interface like:

```
class MyClass {
    // how to store the fields????

    getField1At(Instant i) {...}
    setField1At(Instant i, String ...) {...}

    ...
}
```

I'm currently using the [JTemporal](http://jtemporal.sourceforge.net/) library, and it has a `TemporalAttribute<T>` class, which is like a map: you can do things like `T myAttr.get(Instant i)` to get the version of myAttr at Instant i. I know how to persist a TemporalAttribute in a table with Hibernate (it's simple: I persist the SortedMap used by the TemporalAttribute and you get a table with start and end valid time and the value of the attribute).
The real problem is that here we have multiple attributes.
I have a solution in mind but it's not clear, and I'd like to hear your ideas.

Answer (score 5):

Your project reminds me of [Hibernate Envers](http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html).

> The Envers project aims to enable easy
>   auditing of persistent classes. All
>   that you have to do is annotate your
>   persistent class or some of its
>   properties, that you want to audit,
>   with @Audited. For each audited
>   entity, a table will be created, which
>   will hold the history of changes made
>   to the entity. You can then retrieve
>   and query historical data without much
>   effort.

- choose what you want to audit (on a per attribute basis)
- make your own Revision Entity (that stores informations such as revision number, author, timestamp...)

Using Hibernate Envers for this decouples entities and revision data (in database and in your code).

Comment: I read the Envers manual, but I wasn't able to understand whether it's possible to assign to a revision a Start and End validity time, and not let Envers assign itself. This is what I need, as I don't need only to store revisions, but also to set the time the revision was valid at.

Comment: You can implement your own revision entity (see http://docs.jboss.org/envers/docs/index.html#revisionlog) and add custom timestamps. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: As far I've seen, if I insert my validity dates into the additional revision data I can't specify them in an Envers query (I'm not completely sure about this). I'm digging through the code of the  bitemporal database available with Envers (http://jboss.org/envers/downloads/envers_seam_demo.zip), and I see the fields belongs to a "normal" class, even though the sample code is quite old. There is a bigger problem however (citation from your link): "As revisions are global, you can have at most one revisions entity" - while I need "local" data, i.e. data related to a revision of a specific entity

Comment: At the time being, I've been able to retrieve old data with Envers adding a vt_begin (valid time begin) and vt_end to my class. However, as far as I've seen, Envers considers only one revision at a time, so if I don't check if an old revision exists equals to what I'm setting, I'll have duplicates (I cannot have overlapping periods: only one row for a specific id and a (vt_begin - vt_end)period can exist. I'm experimenting, I'll let you know soon

Comment: Very interesting. As a matter of fact, I don't know if Envers will match your requirements (bending Envers to do something it is not supposed to do is not a great idea).
Keep us posted!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this simply by adding a version number to your domain class.  I did something like this where the Id was a composite between an db assigned number and the version number, but I would advise against that.  Use a normal surrogate key, and if you really want, make the [id, version] tuple a natural key.

You can actually version entire object graphs that way, just by ensuring that the version number is the same for all elements on the graph.  You can then easily go back to any previous version.

You should write a lot of service tests to insure the integrity of the code that manages the version.